# How can I get my own customised Google search page like Firefox?

Tags: google-adsense, google-search

How can I get my own customised Google search page like Firefox?
Example:
http://www.google.co.uk/firefox

Also, can I earn from Adsense like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own Custom Search Engines using Google then monetize it using AdSense. I think the idea is to find useful links on a topic and build a niche engine. I don't know much more than that myself as I haven't used it, but you could start from the documentation page at http://www.google.com/cse/.

Comment: It seems this is the approach Ubuntu take: http://start.ubuntu.com/11.04/

Answer (score 1):

Write your own web browser and then make Google the default search engine. Google may [pay you $57 million](http://techcrunch.com/2008/08/28/mozilla-extends-lucrative-deal-with-google-for-3-years/) so you probably won't need to use Adsense.

Comment: According to your link it was Google who paid Mozilla. I expect you're right about the adsense though!

Comment: I didn't read carefully enough. I've amended my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You become an Adsense premium publisher which isn't something that's easy to do. Most sites that become popular and get a lot of traffic opt to sell their own products or to hook into sweet affiliate advertising deals rather than work with Google like this.